# Manhua where the female lead dies and goes back in time to get revenge

Tags: story-identification, manga

This is in modern times. The female lead's father married her mother for money and was cheating the whole time and had a side piece and another daughter. That daughter took the female lead's boyfriend (maybe fiancé). She gets kidnapped and dies in a basement, then goes back in time to get revenge.

Comment: Are you the same person who posted [this near-identical question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/157183/readertryingtofindmanhua)...? If so, and assuming it's the same manga you're asking about, you should edit your previous question to get it reopened, rather than posting a duplicate of that question.

Comment: If you can no longer access the account you used to post the original question, you'll need to merge your previous account with your new one in order to edit that question. You can merge the two accounts by following the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 1):

It's called [Adore Me Exclusively](https://m.webcomicsapp.com/comic/Adore-Me-Exclusively/61934ce08c252b2cf46d1d07) by Ake Culture. According to the description on WebComics app:

> Wakes up to be a 17-year-old again, Yun Xiangxiang swears that she won't be bullied by anyone again, not by her unfaithful man, stepmother or sister who framed her in her previous life. She will make them pay! But unexpectedly, this Master Fu, alleged to be peevish, is in her way...

Comment: That's cool, but if you are the same user who posted [what appears to be the same question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/266989/i-read-a-manhua-awhile-back-and-forgot-its-name-can-you-help-me-find-it) a bit earlier today, this should really be posted as an answer to that question rather than this duplicate. You can't post an answer to that question right now, because it's closed, but you can get the question reopened if you follow the instructions I provided above.